# SQL 2008 Connection String for Custom Service Account help~

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, connection-string

can anyone help me on connection strings using custom service account.
I have gone through the MSDN guidance on connect to [SQL Server using Windows authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647396.aspx)
but somehow unable to figure out how to get the custom service account to work.

My connection string is as follows:

```
 <add name="GTR.MDFConnectionString" connectionString="Server=SGDB3;Database=GTR;Trusted_Connection=Yes;"/>
```

Have also created the an app pool successfully using the custom service account as identity and checked the application is running under this new app pool.

In the SQL server 2008r database, i have also added the custom service account as a new login to my database GTR with read write access roles

However, when my ASP.NET web application runs and access the database, it throws a login failed sqlexception referencing my personal domain ID and not my custom service ID.
"Cannot open database "GTR" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'ryan'."

Custom service id: SGImport
My domain id: ryan

Can anyone please guide me on whats wrong and how i should get the web application to connect to database as the custom service account and not the user account?

Comment: Your application should impersonate user for your service. Look up .NET impersonation, something like `<identity impersonate="true"          userName="domain\user" password="password" />` in your web.config.

Comment: Thanks for that! However it led to another problem using impersonate and running on local debugger it shows an error 
"Could not load file or assembly 'AjaxControlToolkit' or one of its dependencies. An API call exited abnormally."

I googled and most fixes are saying to add the user i am impersonating to the ASP folders, however for local debug which folder should i be granting the user to any idea?

Comment: Alright granted rights to e impersonated account in my local ASP.net Temp folder and its working now.